# Palindrome from the first 16 *roman* numbers

Tags: sequence, palindrome

Can you concatenate the numbers from I to XVI in some order, such that the resulting 38-letter string is a palindrome?

This puzzle was inspired by a recent puzzle by Dmitry Kamenetsky.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Here is an extension for you: for which $n$ can you concatenate the Roman numbers from 1 to $n$, such that the resulting string is a palindrome?

Comment: Good question!  I originally wanted to ask this for numbers I to XX.  But that doesn't work so I changed it to 16.  n > 16 is not possible.  One constraint is that the number of I, V, X required must be even except at most one.  But n=20 should be ok in that respect.  What happens is that from n=17 you have 3 numbers containing "XV".  The string must contain these in reverse.  But "VX" is invalid in a roman number.  So there must be a split after each "V".  Now there are only 2 numbers ending in "V", so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One such palindrome:

> XIIIVIIIVIIXIIVXVIXXIVXVIIXIIVIIIVIIIX

*Puzzle: stop here and decipher that before continuing.*

> XIII V III VII XI IV XV IX XIV XVI I XII VI II VIII X
>  13 5 3 7 11 4 15 9 14 16 1 12 6 2 8 10

I obtained this solution by finding shorter palindromes using subsets of the numbers.

> Specifically, I started with 14 and 16:
>  XIV XVI <=> IV XV IX
>  Then worked with 8 and 13:
>  XIII V <=> VIII X
>  And resolved the rest, using 7 and 12 in a similar manner:
>  III VII XI <=> I XII VI II

Taking one half of each these to form the first half of the full palindrome yields the final result.